# wff in A iff |A|=2?

Tags: logic

In {<,S (a unary function)}; what is a wff in A iff |A|=2?

Comment: Do we know anything about $S$ or $<$? Like, say, $<$ is a partial or total order?

Answer (score 1):

Without additional information about $S$ or $<$, it is not necessarily possible. For a counterexample, take $S(x)=x$ and $x<y$ true for all $x,y$. The only term-forming construction is $S$, so all terms are of the form $S^n(v_i)$ for some variable $v_i$, and the only predicate forming construction is $<$, so all atomic predicates are of the form $S^n(v_i)<S^m(v_j)$, which is the constant true by our definition. We can thus define a mapping from the sentences of $L$ to the language $T=\{\top\}$ over a universe of one element whose only predicate is $\top$ (which is true) which preserves the truth-value of sentences, and hence we cannot distinguish any nonzero value of $|A|$ with any formula. (We can distinguish $|A|=0$ from $|A|\ne0$ because $\exists x(x<x\vee\lnot x<x)$ is true iff $|A|\ne0$.)

If $<$ is a total order, then we can define equality by $x=y\iff\lnot(x<y\vee y<x)$, so we can distinguish any finite cardinality. For example: $$|A|=2\iff\exists x\exists y, (x\ne y\land\forall z,z=x\lor z=y).$$

Comment: Given that this question was asked at all, I would assume that equality is available as a logical symbol.

Comment: @EricWofsey Wouldn't one usually put $=$ in the signature then? It is not uncommon to study languages which don't have equality, and there is a predicate-forming symbol in the signature so it's not ill-defined (although it is false, which could be considered a warning flag since OP asked for a proof).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are working in first-order logic with equality as a logical symbol, you can use $$\exists x\exists y (\neg(x=y)\wedge\forall z ((z=x)\vee(z=y))).$$

It's a good exercise to think about how this works and see how you could generalize it to give a sentence which holds in $A$ iff $|A|=n$, for any fixed natural number $n$.